# Javascript Objects & Arrays - taking value from one object to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two sets of Data.
They both within them have a 'positionTitle' I want the values from one's positionTitle's to be placed in the other.

The first set of data which is the data I want to keep just with the positions updated from the second, is an object with arrays within it.

```
{

    "id":"00xmlAAA","name":"A","engagementAreas":
    [{"id":"a6q0X0AW","name":"","hasActiveContract":false,"
    engagements":[{"id":"a0s0X000008udz6QAA","name":"M","startDate":"2018-03- 
    22","endDa
    te":"2019-03-22","country":null,"city":null,"type":"Project","members": 
    [{"id":"a0U0X00001HNjm7UAD","account":{"id":"001b00000
    0U7vXfAAJ","fullName":"Edy Liongosari"},"badgeType":null,"endDate":"2019-03- 
    22","engagementRole":"Working Group","position":{
    "id":"a16b0000000B3tgAAC","organizationId":"001b00000062923AAA",
    "organizationName":"a","positionTitle":"Managing Director", <-- here
    "positionLevel":"4-Head of Business Unit/Head of 
    Region","isPrimary":true,"startDate":
```

The second set is one array with objects with arrays.

SECOND SET -

```
[{"account":{"id":"001b000003WnPy1AAF","fullName":"Adnan A. Khan"},"positions":[
{"id":"a","positionTitle":"Senior Manager, Energy","positionLevel":"5-Middle Managem
nt & Advisers","isPrimary":true,"startDate":"2016-10-07","endDate":null}]},{"account":{"id":"0010
X000048DDMsQAO","fullName":"Christine Leong"},"positions":[{"id":"a160X000004nKfhQAE","organizationId":"00
1b0000005gxmlAAA","organizationName":"a","positionTitle":"Managing Director"   <-- here    ,"positionLevel":"4-Head of Bu
siness Unit/Head of Region","isPrimary":true,"startDate":"2018-03-05","endDate":null}]}
,{"account":{"id":"001b000000Gs91HAAR","fullName":"Cora Ansorg"}
```

*The first set of data will have different amounts of areas such as below,
which led to me believing a .map method with a for loop would be quite tricky as i dont have set index's to go to?

```
The first array will have a number of 'engagementareas' {[]}
This will have a number of 'engagementtypes'{[]}
this will have a number of 'engagements'{[]}
this will have a number of 'positions'{}
which will have some 'positionTitle'
```

I was thinking of using an array.map

I can console.log the data like this

```
    console.log('graph data members' + JSON.stringify(graphData.engagementAreas[0].engagementTypes[1].engagements[0].members[0].position.positionTitle))


I can think of using array.map (  (el, i) => 

el.engagementareas.engagementtypes.members[i].
position.positionTitle = a.positions[i].positionTitle


 )
```

Comment: please add valid objects/arrays, your wanted result and what you have tried. please have a look here, too: [mcve]